# How do I create a Dialog with Tabs

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-tabs

Is it possible to create a `Dialog` that has `Tab`s?

If possible, by selecting one of the `Tab`s I have to call an `Activity`, is it possible to pass values ​​through a `Bundle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tabHost class of android for that purpose.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

in the onItemClick in the list, retrieve the customer name and put it in the intent and call the class that expends tabActivity like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", name);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

at the tab activity remove the data from bundle

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, firsttabActivity.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("first", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_shuffle)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, secondtabActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("second", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_shuffle)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

now u can pass the customer name along with the intents in the tab and make the activities extract it and use your own logic to use customer name to retrieve customers details.
i dont know if there is any more effecient way to do it. this just happened to come to my mind first.
i hope it helps.

Comment: I have a class that extends the Activity class (not TabActivity). In such a dialogue and I want to have tabs on this dialogue, is it possible?

Comment: i am a little confused. do u have an activity which shows some data and other stuff and u want to add tabs also to that data? or is it an activity with just tabs?

Comment: In my main activity show a list of customers. Selecting one I have to open a dialogue in which a tab to show me your contact details in another tab your billing information and a map in another tab.

Comment: so in that case u can have an intent in ur onListItemClick which will call a class that extends TabActivity with 2 tabs. and the 2 tabs can have activity which retrieves data of the customer from database based on the bundle data extracted from the calling activity.

Comment: If not too much trouble, could you show me an example?
thank you very much